# preg_replace format into outputted date

Tags: php

I want to replace variables in text so that a user can set a custom date format.

In the simplest example, they can do this....

```
$text = 'The date today is {{current_date|Y-m-d}} isnt it';

$text = preg_replace('/{{current_date\|(.*)}}/', date("$1"), $text);

echo $text;
```

But this returns...

```
The date today is Y-m-d isnt it
```

But I want it to return....

```
The date today is 2020-07-10 isnt it
```

So the date is not being formatted. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The captured date format won't be passed into the `date` function. It will only be available for interpolation into the replacament string. You'll want to use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/{{current_date\|(.*)}}/', function($match) {
    return date($match[1]); 
}, $text);
```

This allows you to pass the captured string into a function for further processing.

Comment: You might want to do some sanitization/validation of the time format, if it's indeed user input. For example, by limiting the `.*` to only `[a-zA-Z/_-]+` characters, and especially not allowing the backslash. Because one could, for example, do something like... `$xss = "\<\s\c\\r\i\p\\t\>\a\l\\e\\r\\t\(\'\!\'\)\;\<\/\s\c\\r\i\p\\t\>"; echo date($xss);`. o_O

Comment: Thanks, yep I sanitise all user input, I just simplified the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is PHP version <=5.6, the below code will work. Later version `/e` is depricated

```
$text = 'The date today is {{current_date|Y-m-d}} isnt it';
$text = preg_replace('/{{current_date\|(.*)}}/e', 'date("$1")', $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: It was deprecated for good reason, and must be used with caution equal to anything you might pass into `eval`. From the manual: *"**Caution:** 
Use of this modifier is discouraged, as it can easily introduce remote code execution vulnerabilities. To prevent these, the preg_replace_callback() function should be used instead."* Also, PHP 5.6 became EOL in end of 2018, incl. no new security fixes, and as such should no longer be deployed. https://www.php.net/eol.php